# БД Firebase не отображает данные на реальных устройствах при установке через Google Play

Tags: java, android, google-play, firebase-database

В своём приложении храню данные пользователя в Firebase, используя при этом анонимную авторизацию.В отдельном фрагменте отображаю часть данных пользователя(имя и счёт), реализовав тем самым список лидеров который ограничивается 50-ю пользователями. Когда запускаю в Android Studio на эмуляторах либо на реальном устройстве через кабель usb всё исправно работает, но при загрузке приложения в Google Play и установке оттуда данные не отображаются. Код activity(фрагмента) представлен ниже:

```
package com.awr.cinemageek.features;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.awr.cinemageek.R;
import com.awr.cinemageek.model.UserAdapter;
import com.awr.cinemageek.model.UserModel;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Liders_Fragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<UserModel> result;
    private List<UserModel> short_result;
    private UserAdapter adapter;
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        reference=database.getReference("User");
        short_result=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
            short_result.add(new UserModel("Пусто","","",0,0));
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_best,
                container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.user_list);
        LinearLayoutManager lim = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        lim.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lim);
        adapter = new UserAdapter(short_result);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        updateList();
        return view;
    }

    private void updateList()
    {
        reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                result.add(snapshot.getValue(UserModel.class));
                Collections.sort(result);
                if(result.size()>0) {
                    if (result.size() > 50) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                            short_result.set(i, result.get(i));
                        }
                    } else for (int i = 0; i < result.size() - 1; i++) {
                        short_result.set(i, result.get(i));
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            }
            
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Код item-а из recycleview представлен ниже :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@null"

    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_razd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
       >
    </TextView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/user"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_razd"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </ImageView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_name"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:fontFamily="@font/marvin"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/avatar"
    android:layout_below="@id/text_razd"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:text="Мистер исключит"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_linear2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundcorner4"
        android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
        android:paddingVertical="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/avatar"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
         >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_stars"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/font11"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="30"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="19sp">
        </TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stars_score"
            android:layout_width="26dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:background="@drawable/star_for_icon">

        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/position"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/avatar"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundcorner2"
        android:fontFamily="@font/font2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp">
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: На эмуляторе через Android Studio][image: На реальном устройстве через Google play]

Comment: Скорее всего (99% вероятности) вы неосторожно согласились под давлением гугла на необязательное (вроде бы пока ещё) убирание вашей подписи с приложения и заменой оной на подпись корпорации зла. Это отменить уже нельзя и вам придётся с этим жить или перевыпускать приложение заново, с новым пакетом и прочим. Простым же способом решить проблему будет прописывание в настройках Firebase проекта отпечатка ключа гугла, взятого из консоли разработчика в магазине.

Comment: Я действительно согласился на подпись гуглом моего приложения как вы и сказали) Но зайдя в настройки firebase увидел что там прописаны именно ключи гугла и ещё 2 мне неизвестных (делал это давно, уже не помню откуда их взял). По логике ключи от гугла должны срабатывать, так как я прочитал что гугл проверяет ключ загрузки пользователя и заменяет его на свой. Но поэкспериментировав все же не получил желаемый результат. Странным остался тот факт, что пользователи добавляются в БД, но при чтении возвращаются пустые данные.

Comment: Очень странно. По идее, 3 ваших ключа должны быть такими: дебажный с компа где студия, загрузочный, которым подписано то, что вы в магазин отправляете и тот, которым гугл подписывает приложение. Попробуйте выяснить, действительно ли послений в Firebase прописан. Вот тут есть инструкция как подлучить подпись из APK https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331469/how-do-i-find-out-which-keystore-was-used-to-sign-an-app. APK из магазина можно по разному вытаскивать, попробуйте, например (на свой страх и риск) вот это приложение: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ext.ui&hl=en_US&gl=US

Comment: Хм, установил приложение, которое вы посоветовали, получил апк приложения из GP и по инструкции из ссылки не смог найти файл .RSA, проверил на другом приложении(взял Пикабу) там он есть. Также проверил подпись загрузочным ключом через консоль, ключ совпал с тем что прописан в консоли разработчика. Но при проверке тем же способом подписи извлеченного апк из приложения установленного через GP получил сообщение Not a signed jar file(что и предполагалось вначале,т.к. .RSA файл отсутствует). Что ещё более странно, т.е. подписанный мной файл,который я загружаю устроил гугл, но он не подписал его?)

Comment: По ссылке есть и другие способы, без нужды в RSA файле. Попробуйте над APK из магазина такое выполнить: `keytool -printcert -jarfile app.apk`

Comment: К сожалению пробовал , именно это я пробовал когда написал, что проверял ключ через консоль и получил Not a signed jar file, не помогло(

Comment: Очень странно. У вас, случаем, не aab, вместо apk в маркет заливается? Может в этом дело?